# PHP LDAP returning partial data

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am accessing an Active Directory server via PHP's ldap_* functions.  Part of the task is to determine application permissions based on AD group membership.  For my user this works correctly, for some other users, the "memberOf" field is not part of the returned data.  What would cause this attribute to be missing?  What can I do to determine group membership in its absence?

```
$ds = ldap_connect($ldap['host']);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
if ($ds) {
    $r  = ldap_bind($ds, $ldap['user'], $ldap['pass']);
    $sr = ldap_search($ds, $ldap['path'], "samaccountname=".$username, array(), 0, 1000, 5);
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
}
```

Comment: Are those users actually a member of any groups? It's possible memberOf is empty.

Comment: Yes.  Checking the user via the Windows AD interface reveals expected membership.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was able to work around this problem by pulling all the members of the group and searching the results for the current user.  I still don't know why the data was missing from the user pull.

```
$ds = ldap_connect($ldap['host']);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
if ($ds) {
    $r  = ldap_bind($ds, $ldap['user'], $ldap['pass']);
    $sr = ldap_search($ds, $group, "cn=*", array(), 0, 1000, 5);
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
}
foreach ($info[0]['member'] as $member) {
    if ($member == $currentUserDistinguishedName) {
        // Do Authorized stuff
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a small note, memberOf will be blank if they are only a member of the domain users group. That is actually considered their primary group and will not show up in memberOf. In fact, memberOf itself is just a calculated value and not actually stored with the LDAP user. Not sure if this is what you ran into, but it's worth mentioning.